# Round function no longer works with mice output

Tags: r, rounding, r-mice

Since updating R to 4.0.0 and re-installing `mice` it seems that the `round()` function no longer works on mice output but yields an error message.

For example (using iris dataset):

```
library(missForest) # for the prodNA function
library(mice)       # for the imputations

#Creating dataset with missing values (NAs)
iris.mis <- prodNA(iris, noNA = 0.1)
head(iris.mis)

#Imputation
imputed_data <- mice(data = iris.mis, m = 5, method = "pmm", 
    maxit = 50, seed = 500)
model <- with(data = imputed_data, lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width))
round(summary(pool(model), conf.int = TRUE, exponentiate = TRUE), 2)
```

This yields the error message:

> Error in Math.data.frame(list(term = 1:2, estimate = c(760.13466726231,  : 
>     non-numeric variable(s) in data frame: term

Using `summary(pool(model), conf.int = T, exponentiate = T)` works just fine.

Before updating R and mice I've never had issues with the round function in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly why this would have changed, but the [NEWS file for mice](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/news/news.html)  says in version 3.8

> There is now a more flexible `pool()` function that integrates better with the `broom` and `broom.mixed` packages.

It makes sense that row names would have been changed to a `term` column instead, as this is more compatible with tidyverse machinery (like `broom` and `broom.mixed`).

You can ask R to round all but the first column:

```
ss <- summary(pool(model), conf.int = TRUE, exponentiate = TRUE)
ss[-1] <- round(ss[-1],2)
ss
##          term estimate std.error statistic     df p.value  2.5 %  97.5 %
## 1 (Intercept)   670.98      0.48     13.69 143.68    0.00 262.19 1717.15
## 2 Sepal.Width     0.80      0.15     -1.44 143.36    0.15   0.59    1.09
```

If you like tidyverse you could

```
mutate_if(ss,is.numeric, round, 2)
```

Comment: It appears to be that Stef ["bugfixed" `mice 3.8.0`](https://stefvanbuuren.name/mice/news/index.html) to sympathize more with broom/tidyverse by extending the `pool` function. So I conclude we no longer have row names but this "great" `term` variable.